# JavaScript checar se o usuário do Windows está cadastrado no Banco MS Access

Tags: javascript, windows, microsoft-access

A necessidade é checar se o usuário do Windows está cadastrado no Banco de dados Ms Access (Banco em rede), mas não está funcionando como deveria. Acho que o problema está na variável strUserName dentro do select.

Já tentei de varias maneiras mas ainda não achei a solução!

Alguém sabe como resolvo isso?

```js
< html > < body >


  <!-- PEGA USUARIO LOGADO NO WINDOWS -->

< script type = "text/javascript" >
var objNet = new ActiveXObject("WScript.NetWork");
var strUserName = objNet.UserName;
var strDomain = objNet.UserDomain;


document.write("Usuário: ", strUserName);



function abreRelJC() {

  var adoConn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
  var adoRS = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

  adoConn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='P:\\PCP\\GERENCIAL\\System\\GERENCIAL_be.mdb'");
  adoRS.Open("Select * From CadastroUser WHERE UsuarioRelatorioGerencial = strUserName", adoConn, 1, 3);

  var Userbanco = adoRS.fields("UsuarioRelatorioGerencial").value;



  if (Userbanco == strUserName) {

    document.write("Ok! usuário cadastrado");

    adoRS.Close();
    adoConn.Close();
  } else {

    document.write("Usuário pendente de cadastro!");

    adoRS.Close();
    adoConn.Close();
  }

}


< /script>


<br / > < br / >


< input type = "button"
onclick = "abreRelJC()"
value = "Testa usuáro"
style = "font-size:20px; color:SlateGray" / >


  < /body>< /html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Já tentou:

```
adoRS.Open("Select * From CadastroUser WHERE UsuarioRelatorioGerencial = " + strUserName, adoConn, 1, 3, 1);
```

?

Da mesma maneira no document.write:

```
document.write("Usuário: " +  strUserName);
```

Caso o console de rede ou do javascript retorne algum erro, favor postá-lo

Correção: Tentar
     adoRS.Open("Select * From CadastroUser WHERE UsuarioRelatorioGerencial = " + strUserName, adoConn, 1, 3, 1);

Comment: Isso provavelmente funcione. Não sei a finalidade dessa aplicação mas gostaria de alertar a falha de segurança, já que o acesso ao banco de dados está no Cliente possibilitando o mesmo a alterar o script SQL e realizar um SQL inject.

Comment: Então jefissu, eu tinha tentando e e fica na mesma, o primeiro document.write ("Usuário: ", strUserName); até exibe o usuário do Windows, mas os document.write dentro do If não funcionam. ERRO: Mensagem: Nenhum valor foi fornecido para um ou mais parâmetros necessários.
Linha: 20
Caractere: 12
Código: 0
URI: file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/asimoes/Desktop/pergunta%20javascript.html

Comment: Luã, obrigado pela dica! vou me atentar apesar desse script rodar apenas na intranet, ele será apenas um menu que abrira alguns documentos .xlsx que estão na rede, mas só poderão acessar os usuários que estiverem cadastrados em um banco Access.

Comment: Segundo  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676573(v=vs.85).aspx Parece-me que este pede 5 parâmetros ao invés de 4... Tente colocar mais um parâmetro no final do open valendo 1

Comment: @jefissu, também não funcionou, mas notei que se substituir a variável strUserName no Select pelo usuário do windows no meu caso "asimoes", funciona corretamente, então o problema deve estar em o select não reconhecer a variável  strUserName que que contem valor pego pelo método objNet.UserName; que é o usuário do windows! será que é preciso converter strUserName para alguma outra forma antes de passa-lo no Select?

Comment: Se vc executar no console do javascript ou no código:
    alert(strUserName)
ou console.log(strUserName) o que ele retorna?